# JBoss Wildly Kie Server gives warning for unable to load module-info.class

Tags: wildfly, drools, kie

When I publish rule artifact to Kie-Server it throws the following warning,

WARN  [org.kie.server.services.drools.DroolsKieServerExtension] (default task-1) Unexpected error while create instance of type .module-info due to Failed to link /module-info (Module "deployment.kie-server.war" from Service Module Loader): /module-info is not a class because access_flag ACC_MODULE is set

It still works but tons of these warnings gets printed. The artifact being published contains some java class files and a dependency POM. There are 2 dependencies com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.3 and commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6

The runtime is Java 11 which supports the module system, why am getting this error?